# C++: difference between 0. and 0.0?

Tags: c++, c, grammar, double-precision

I am well aware of the difference between `0` and `0.0` (int and double).

But is there any difference between `0.` and `0.0` ( please note the . )?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Axel

Comment: No semantic difference (well, there is the difference of one extra byte in your source code :p). But, slightly related to this, there IS a difference between +0.0 and -0.0. Have fun!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. Both literals are double. From the C++-Grammar:

```
fractional-constant:
    digit-sequenceopt . digit-sequence
    digit-sequence .
```

See: [Hyperlinked C++ BNF Grammar](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#fractional-constant)

Comment: Really? that's strange. Howcome  cout << typeid(0).name() << " " << typeid(0.0).name();
prints "i d"?

Comment: `typeid(0)` <-- that's an *int*. See the '.' at the end of the third code-line.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

Comment: Yes there is. Type cout << typeid(0).name() << " " << typeid(0.0).name(); (Removed the downvote, I will downvote later if I am correct)

Comment: `typeid(0).name()` is using an int - note the lack of a trailing decimal place. Try `cout << typeid(0.).name() << " " << typeid(0.0).name();` and you'll see they're the same.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can also write .0 as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Just having the `.` as part of the number identifies it as a floating point type.

This:

```
 cout << (5 / 2) << endl;
 cout << (5. / 2) << endl;
 cout << (5.0 / 2) << endl;
```

Prints this:

```
 2
 2.5
 2.5
```

You can see that the first line uses integer division (because both values are integers), whereas `5.` and `5.0` both get identified as floating point types, and so they trigger "normal division."

Answer (score -3):

`0` is of type int but can be casted to double and `0.0` is of type double but can be casted to int.
Both casts are implicit.

Comment: The question explicitly asks about `0.`; it even says "note the .".